# How to insert a different selectedindex combobox value into database?

Tags: c#

In my project i have a countries combobox (PaysCmBx0) that is filled from countries database table [Pays] column [pays], what i want to do is when i select a country in the combobox it insert the Alpha country code token from the Alpha country code column [Alpha2] in another table (exemple : United-states = US).

so when i select a country from the combobox it does nothing it's intserting the same value.

My table look like this:

```
        [Aplha2]       [Pays]
         GB           United Kingdom
         IM           Isle of Man
         TZ           United Republic Of Tanzania
         US           United States
         BF           Burkina Faso
         UY           Uruguay
         UZ           Uzbekistan
```

here's my code :

```
  void Fillcombo()
    {

        string Query = "SELECT * FROM Pays";


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
        SqlDataReader myRead;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            myRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myRead.Read())
            {
                string sName = myRead["Pays"].ToString();
                PaysCmBx0.Items.Add(sName);
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }


    }



     private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {                 
                string Query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Adresses] ([idParent],[Type] ,[Adresse0],[Adresse1],[Adresse2],[CPT],[Ville],[Pays]) VALUES ('"+Contact.idContact+"','" + TypeAdrCmBx.Text+ "','" + this.AdrTxtBx0.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx1.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx2.Text + "','" + this.CptTxtBx.Text + "','" + this.VilleTxtBx.Text + "','" + this.PaysCmBx0.Text + "')";                    

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader Read;

                try
                {
                 Read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void PaysCmBx0_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Query1 = "SELECT * FROM Pays  WHERE Pays='" + PaysCmBx0.Text + "'";


        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, con);
        SqlDataReader myRead;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            myRead = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (myRead.Read())
            {
                string Code_Pays = myRead["Alpha2"].ToString();

               PaysCmBx0.SelectedIndex.Equals(Code_Pays);
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya When i select the item in the combobox it does nothing actually

Comment: @Jimmy means when the selection changed this `PaysCmBx0_SelectedIndexChanged` this event is not firing?

Comment: @Jimmy did you  debug the code of `PaysCmBx0_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every one i fund a solutions for this :

i create a function that gets the country code corresponding to what's selected in the combobox:

```
     private string get_code_pays(string nom_pays)
    {
        string Query1 = "SELECT * FROM Pays  WHERE Pays='" + PaysCmBx0.Text + "'";
        string Code_Pays="";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, con);
        SqlDataReader myRead;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            myRead = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (myRead.Read())
            {
                 Code_Pays = myRead["Alpha2"].ToString();

                PaysCmBx0.SelectedIndex.Equals(Code_Pays);
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
        return Code_Pays;
    }
```

and then call my funtion with the parameter in my insert:

```
         string Query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Adresses] ([idParent],[Type] ,[Adresse0],[Adresse1],[Adresse2],[CPT],[Ville],[Pays]) VALUES ('"+Contact.idContact+"','" + A + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx0.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx1.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx2.Text + "','" + this.CptTxtBx.Text + "','" + this.VilleTxtBx.Text + "','" + get_code_pays( this.PaysCmBx0.Text) + "')";
```